# Best way to smooth out object

Tags: rendering

[image: Pipe Section]

Hey guys. Hoping you can help me out. I've got a section of pipes that was poorly modeled to start and I am trying to see if blender has any tools to help smooth these out for rendering. I am just trying to render this model and the rest of the objects look good except for this. I am fairly new to blender, sorry.

I have already tried the subdivision surface and smooth modifiers. Any other ideas?

Comment: you've already tried subsurf and smooth and you still have this result? that's weird... by the way, I guess you're talking about smooth shading, and not modifier... perhaps share a part of your object so that we can see why it doesn't smooth more than that...

Comment: No, I was referring to the smooth and corrective smooth modifiers, but even the smooth shading doesn't do much for it. I can share it, but what's the best way? When I save just the pipes section as a blender file, it is 85MB.

Comment: oh ok I don't know this modifier. You can just keep only one pipe and upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You could use https://www.myairbridge.com for the whole object. Btw cases like this SubDiv solves everytime. From the picture it looks the pipes are modeled some weird way cause there are some incosistencies in the polyflow. Share with as so we could explore. Usual way to model this kinda object is to extrude circle along path or extrude it, resize and rotate manually...

Comment: I figured out how to select faces and toggled the limit faces to visible option to allow easier deletion of unneeded vertices. Here's the file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5476" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5476/)

Comment: Jan, I did try the SubDiv and it did create a lot more faces, but didn't change smoothness of object. I'm not sure why they decided to model this way because the rest of the pipes in full model are done properly and look great when rendered. They even forgot a y-pipe section at the top which is even more fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipes are made from faces that are disconnected, this keeps each face as a flat surface.

In edit mode, select everything <kbd>A</kbd> and remove doubles <kbd>W</kbd>*->Remove Doubles*. You may also want to use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to turn all the triangles into quads to cleanup the mesh.